# How to solve this possible permutation/combinations problem?

Tags: permutations, combinations

This is not a homework question, just more of a question that sort of had me scratching my head. Although I'm in upper level math courses I honestly don't remember much about permutation or combinations, but I believe this question is solved using one or both of these. Searching for similar questions online didn't turn up much help.

There are x+y different books on the shelf, x books have blue binding, and y books have white bindings.

a) how many ways can the books be arranged so that the books with blue bindings occupy the first x positions?

b) how many ways can we arrange the books so the books with blue bindings are together?

My attempt at it for (a) was 
$\frac{(x+y)!}{((x+y)-x)!}$
But after doing that I wasn't sure. I didn't even attempt (b).

Answer (score 1):

a)Take two strings, one whith only $x$ blue letters and one with only $y$ white letters, if you glue those two together you get a string with $x+y$ letters with the first $x$ blue.
So you have $x!y!$ different strings.

b) If I understood the question you have to put all the blue books on the shelf together.

You have $y+1$ (thank's to grand_chat) spaces to put the books and then you have the same problem as above, so $(y+1)(x!y!)$

Comment: In (b) there are $y+1$ ways to insert an arrangement of blue books given an arrangement of white books: the block of blues are all to the left of the white (1 way), or all to the right of the white (1 way), or squeezed inside the white ($y-1$ ways).